# How to iterate a collection of comment to get all different levels of comment replies?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a comment model for a post. The nested comment can be many levels deep. For this, I have created a `comments` collection inside the `post` collection. A single comment document has the following structure

```
content: string,
author: {
    username: string,
    userID: string
},
isRootComment: bool,
childComments: [id1, id2, id3],
childOfCommentID: string
```

Now I want to iterate over `comments` collection in such a manner so that it has the following structure on a web page

```
root-comment:A
       child-comment:1
               subchild-comment:1
               subchild-comment:2
       child-comment:2
               subchild-comment:1
root-comment:B
       child-comment:1
               subchild-comment:1
       child-comment:2
```

To get all root-level comments I can query as `where("isRootComment", "==", true)`. But How to iterate over all the level of comments? Can you give me an idea to do this?

Comment: I would not use a subcollection at all here.  I would just put all comments in a single collection, and add fields to them that let you filter for the ones you want.  The size of the collectioon is never going to be an issue as long as you only filter for the comments you want.

Comment: can you tell me how can I proceed with the model I have

Comment: I believe that this could use something like when you iterate through pointers,

something like, check if root has children, if it does, add children to an array to get the sub-comment, and do this again but for children until you don't find more children. is the basic idea that I can think of while trying to make a search of this type. maybe someone can post something more efficient.

Comment: I need a detailed explained answer